# Automatically Run Macro before Pivot Table Refresh

Tags: vba

I want to run a macro automatically on pivot refresh event, but challenge here is macros has run first then pivot has to get refresh

I tried all these event, none of these are working me

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableAfterValueChange(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal TargetRange As Range)
    MsgBox "Worksheet_PivotTableAfterValueChange"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeAllocateChanges(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal ValueChangeStart As Long, ByVal ValueChangeEnd As Long, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeAllocateChanges"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeCommitChanges(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal ValueChangeStart As Long, ByVal ValueChangeEnd As Long, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeCommitChanges"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal ValueChangeStart As Long, ByVal ValueChangeEnd As Long)
    MsgBox "Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges"
End Sub
```

Can any one help me on this please..? Thanks in advance

refer this link for more info : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/automatically-executing-a-macro-when-i-refresh/d11c424c-4ba5-4ba1-9454-e2c0072cdb7f

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. What have you already tried? Do have some specific code you're stuck on? Or is this a "give-me-the-code" question?

Comment: Hi Mistella, thanks for looking into my query, I have edited my query I hope you will convey my issue

Comment: Then you may need to put logic conditionals inside one or more of the event procedures to account for those nuances.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be simpler to have one of the events call the macro, and then at the end of the macro disable events, refresh the pivottable (again), then re-enable events? -- Note that the disabling/re-enabling of events would be important for preventing a never-ending loop.

Comment: Maybe the other way round: At the end of your macro you can `PivotTable.RefreshTable` or `PivotCache.Refresh`.